# Regex:Match lines with 7 same letters in two words of the line

Tags: regex, grep

I have the passwd file with each line being like that:

```
abcdefg:x:2029:1040:Hasan abcdefg:/home/student/x0203/abcdefg:/bin/bash
ijklmnop:x:2029:1040:Bob ijklmnop:/home/student/x0203/ijklmnop:/bin/bash
man:x:2029:1040:Sponger man:/home/student/x0203/ijklmnop:/bin/bash
```

I want to match all lines that have 7 letters or more from their name in the user name for example with the above lines i want to match:

```
abcdefg:x:2029:1040:Hasan abcdefg:/home/student/x0203/abcdefg:/bin/bash
ijklmnop:x:2029:1040:Bob ijklmnop:/home/student/x0203/ijklmnop:/bin/bash
```

I wrote the folowing :

```
egrep '.*(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.).*[:].*[:].*[:].*[:].*\1\2\3\4\5\6\7.*[:].*[:].*' passdw
```

but this matches only the users that have a 7 letter username

```
abcdefg:x:2029:1040:Hasan abcdefg:/home/student/x0203/abcdefg:/bin/bash
```

This is for a school project and i have to use grep and regex so awk will not do it .I dont ask for the whole awnser here i did the most ,i just dont know why its not workign.

Comment: It works as you want for me. BTW, you can simplify all those dots to `(.{7})` and then match it with `\1`.

Comment: You also don't need brackets around `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This grep should work:

```
grep -iP '([^:])([^:])([^:])([^:])([^:])([^:])([^:])([^:]*:){4}[^:]*?\1\2\3\4\5\6\7'
```

Comment: i am not sure if i understand it correct but this will show the users that have a username of more or 7 character,so if i have a user with username ksmiths and his name is Konsta Smiths it will show him too. I dont want that

Comment: @SteveL: So you want lines where user's real names have more than 7 characters?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right but if intent is to pick all lines with user's full names having more than 7 chars then last line should also be picked since user's full name is: `Sponger man`

Comment: I want to match lines that have for example : name kjohanson and user name  Kevin Johanson(here matches Johanson)  and NOT username kjohner and name kevin johner(cause johner has 6 chars)

Comment: Alright got you, let me see how I can incorporate that in my answer.

Comment: nop  this only gives me 3 results(out of 1400,with 425 to be the correct) my original regex was giving 84.I am really starting to getting angry here!why nothing  works!

Comment: Could it because of case comparison. Let me add `-i` as well.

Comment: Better to use `-P` as well for Perl regex capabilities, pls see the latest edit using `grep -iP`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regexes for this!  Write a simple parser that splits apart the fields then compares the username and the name.